# Azure Data Factory with Integration Runtime - Delete (or move) file after copy

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an on premise server with the Microsoft Integration Runtime installed.
In Azure Data Factory V2 I created a pipeline that copies files from the on premise server to a blob storage.

After a successful transfer I need to delete the files on the on premise server. I am not able to find a solution for this in the documentation. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply moving the file then you can use a Binary dataset in a copy activity. This combination makes a checkbox setting visible that when enabled will automatically delete the file once the copy operation completes. This is a little nicer as you do not need the extra delete activity and the file is "moved" only if the copy operation is a success.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Recently Azure Data Factory introduced a [Delete Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-factory/delete-activity) to delete files or folders from on-premise storage stores or cloud storage stores.

Answer (score 2):

You have the option to call Azure Automation using webhooks, with the web activity. In Azure Automation you can program a powershell or python script with a Hybrid Runbook Worker to delete the file from the on premise server. You can read more on this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker

Another easier option would be to program a script to be run on the server with the windows task scheduler where you run a script to delete the file. Make sure you program the script to be run after data factory has copied the files to the blob, and that's it!

Hope this helped!